# How do I make the radio controls on custom page two distinct groups in Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

In my application I have this settings window:

[image: Settings]

I had the idea of replicating this window as best as possible in my Inno Setup Installer.

At the moment I have the following code:

```pascal
procedure pageAutoBackup_Create;
var
    { Controls }
    pageAutoBackup: TWizardPage;
    btnSelectBackupFolder: TNewButton;
    textBackupFolder: TNewEdit;
    lblWhereToBackup: TLabel;
    lblPromptMode: TLabel;
    comboPromptMode: TNewComboBox;
    lblReminder: TLabel;
    radioBackupModeManual: TNewRadioButton;
    radioBackupModeAuto: TNewRadioButton;
    lblHowToBackup: TLabel;
    radioBackupHowEssential: TNewRadioButton;
    radioBackupHowComplete: TNewRadioButton;
    radioBackupHowNone: TNewRadioButton;
    lblWhatToBackup: TLabel;
begin
    pageAutoBackup := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Automatic Backup', 'Configure automatic backup settings.');

    { lblWhatToBackup (TLabel) }
    lblWhatToBackup := TLabel.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    lblWhatToBackup.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    lblWhatToBackup.Enabled := True;
    lblWhatToBackup.Visible := True;
    lblWhatToBackup.Left := ScaleX(0);
    lblWhatToBackup.Top := ScaleY(10);
    lblWhatToBackup.Width := ScaleX(100);
    lblWhatToBackup.Height := ScaleY(17);
    lblWhatToBackup.Font.Color := $000000;
    lblWhatToBackup.Color := $F0F0F0;
    lblWhatToBackup.Caption := 'What to backup:';

    { radioBackupHowNone (TNewRadioButton) }
    radioBackupHowNone := TNewRadioButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    radioBackupHowNone.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    radioBackupHowNone.Enabled := True;
    radioBackupHowNone.Visible := True;
    radioBackupHowNone.Left := ScaleX(10);
    radioBackupHowNone.Top := ScaleY(30);
    radioBackupHowNone.Width := ScaleX(476);
    radioBackupHowNone.Height := ScaleY(18);
    radioBackupHowNone.Checked := False;
    radioBackupHowNone.Font.Color := $000000;
    radioBackupHowNone.Color := $F0F0F0;
    radioBackupHowNone.Caption := 'Don''t perform any backup when the program shuts down';

    { radioBackupHowComplete (TNewRadioButton) }
    radioBackupHowComplete := TNewRadioButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    radioBackupHowComplete.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Enabled := True;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Visible := True;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Left := ScaleX(10);
    radioBackupHowComplete.Top := ScaleY(54);
    radioBackupHowComplete.Width := ScaleX(478);
    radioBackupHowComplete.Height := ScaleY(19);
    radioBackupHowComplete.Checked := False;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Font.Color := $000000;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Color := $F0F0F0;
    radioBackupHowComplete.Caption := 'Make a complete backup when the program shuts down';

    { radioBackupHowEssential (TNewRadioButton) }
    radioBackupHowEssential := TNewRadioButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    radioBackupHowEssential.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Enabled := True;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Visible := True;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Left := ScaleX(10);
    radioBackupHowEssential.Top := ScaleY(78);
    radioBackupHowEssential.Width := ScaleX(472);
    radioBackupHowEssential.Height := ScaleY(18);
    radioBackupHowEssential.Checked := False;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Font.Color := $000000;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Color := $F0F0F0;
    radioBackupHowEssential.Caption := 'Only make an essential backup when the program shuts down';

    { lblHowToBackup (TLabel) }
    lblHowToBackup := TLabel.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    lblHowToBackup.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    lblHowToBackup.Enabled := True;
    lblHowToBackup.Visible := True;
    lblHowToBackup.Left := ScaleX(0);
    lblHowToBackup.Top := ScaleY(110);
    lblHowToBackup.Width := ScaleX(100);
    lblHowToBackup.Height := ScaleY(17);
    lblHowToBackup.Font.Color := $000000;
    lblHowToBackup.Color := $F0F0F0;
    lblHowToBackup.Caption := 'How to backup:';

    { radioBackupModeAuto (TNewRadioButton) }
    radioBackupModeAuto := TNewRadioButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    radioBackupModeAuto.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Enabled := True;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Visible := True;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Left := ScaleX(10);
    radioBackupModeAuto.Top := ScaleY(129);
    radioBackupModeAuto.Width := ScaleX(481);
    radioBackupModeAuto.Height := ScaleY(20);
    radioBackupModeAuto.Checked := False;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Font.Color := $000000;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Color := $F0F0F0;
    radioBackupModeAuto.Caption := 'Perform automatically when the program is shut down';

    { radioBackupModeManual (TNewRadioButton) }
    radioBackupModeManual := TNewRadioButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    radioBackupModeManual.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    radioBackupModeManual.Enabled := True;
    radioBackupModeManual.Visible := True;
    radioBackupModeManual.Left := ScaleX(10);
    radioBackupModeManual.Top := ScaleY(155);
    radioBackupModeManual.Width := ScaleX(479);
    radioBackupModeManual.Height := ScaleY(19);
    radioBackupModeManual.Checked := False;
    radioBackupModeManual.Font.Color := $000000;
    radioBackupModeManual.Color := $F0F0F0;
    radioBackupModeManual.Caption := 'Prompt the user when the program is shut down';

    { lblPromptMode (TLabel) }
    lblPromptMode := TLabel.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    lblPromptMode.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    lblPromptMode.Enabled := True;
    lblPromptMode.Visible := True;
    lblPromptMode.Left := ScaleX(10);
    lblPromptMode.Top := ScaleY(190);
    lblPromptMode.Width := ScaleX(482);
    lblPromptMode.Height := ScaleY(19);
    lblPromptMode.Font.Color := $000000;
    lblPromptMode.Color := $F0F0F0;
    lblPromptMode.Caption := 'Also prompt to backup at the following intervals while the application is running:';

    { comboPromptMode (TNewComboBox) }
    comboPromptMode := TNewComboBox.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    comboPromptMode.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    comboPromptMode.Enabled := True;
    comboPromptMode.Visible := True;
    comboPromptMode.Left := ScaleX(10);
    comboPromptMode.Top := ScaleY(207);
    comboPromptMode.Width := ScaleX(483);
    comboPromptMode.Height := ScaleY(21);
    comboPromptMode.Font.Color := $000000;
    comboPromptMode.ItemIndex := 0;
    comboPromptMode.Color := $FFFFFF;
    comboPromptMode.Items.Add('Never prompt to backup');
    comboPromptMode.Items.Add('Prompt to backup everyday');
    comboPromptMode.Items.Add('Prompt to backup once a week');
    comboPromptMode.Items.Add('Prompt to backup once a month');
    comboPromptMode.Items.Add('');

    { lblReminder (TLabel) }
    lblReminder := TLabel.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    lblReminder.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    lblReminder.Enabled := True;
    lblReminder.Visible := True;
    lblReminder.Left := ScaleX(20);
    lblReminder.Top := ScaleY(236);
    lblReminder.Width := ScaleX(481);
    lblReminder.Height := ScaleY(23);
    lblReminder.Font.Color := $000000;
    lblReminder.Color := $F0F0F0;
    lblReminder.Caption := '(You should restart the application atleast once a week to let it perform database maintenance)';

    { lblWhereToBackup (TLabel) }
    lblWhereToBackup := TLabel.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    lblWhereToBackup.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    lblWhereToBackup.Enabled := True;
    lblWhereToBackup.Visible := True;
    lblWhereToBackup.Left := ScaleX(0);
    lblWhereToBackup.Top := ScaleY(269);
    lblWhereToBackup.Width := ScaleX(100);
    lblWhereToBackup.Height := ScaleY(15);
    lblWhereToBackup.Font.Color := $000000;
    lblWhereToBackup.Color := $F0F0F0;
    lblWhereToBackup.Caption := 'Where to backup:';

    { textBackupFolder (TNewEdit) }
    textBackupFolder := TNewEdit.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    textBackupFolder.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    textBackupFolder.Enabled := True;
    textBackupFolder.Visible := True;
    textBackupFolder.Left := ScaleX(10);
    textBackupFolder.Top := ScaleY(286);
    textBackupFolder.Width := ScaleX(400);
    textBackupFolder.Height := ScaleY(20);
    textBackupFolder.Font.Color := $000000;
    textBackupFolder.Color := $F0F0F0;

    { btnSelectBackupFolder (TNewButton) }
    btnSelectBackupFolder := TNewButton.Create(pageAutoBackup);
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Parent := pageAutoBackup.Surface;
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Enabled := True;
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Visible := True;
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Left := ScaleX(425);
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Top := ScaleY(286);
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Width := ScaleX(75);
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Height := ScaleY(23);
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Caption := 'Browse ...';

end;
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image: Backup Settings - Inno]

My initial question is:

I have two radio groups:

- What to backup
- How to backup

At the moment my radio controls are acting as one big group. How do I make it two distinct radio group modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, radio buttons with the same container control belong to the same group.

If you need separate groups, you have to put the radio buttons to separate container controls. In your application, you solve that by putting them into different group boxes.

The groups boxes are unfortunately not supported by Inno Setup.

Instead, you can use [`TPanel` control](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TPanel). It can be configured to render completely seamless:

```pascal
Panel := TPanel.Create(WizardForm);
Panel.Caption := '';
Panel.BevelOuter := bvNone;
Panel.BevelInner := bvNone; { default }
Panel.BevelKind := bkNone;
```

If you put your radio buttons on separate panels, your custom page can still look exactly like it does.

---

Another option is to use [`TNewCheckListBox`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewCheckListBox) with its `AddGroup`.

```pascal
PageAutoBackup := CreateCustomPage(...);

CheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(WizardForm);

CheckListBox.Parent := PageAutoBackup.Surface;
CheckListBox.Top := WizardForm.SelectTasksLabel.Top;
CheckListBox.Width := WizardForm.TasksList.Width;
CheckListBox.Left := WizardForm.TasksList.Left;
CheckListBox.Height :=
  WizardForm.TasksList.Top + WizardForm.TasksList.Height - CheckListBox.Top;

CheckListBox.WantTabs := True;
CheckListBox.Color := clBtnFace;
CheckListBox.BorderStyle := bsNone;

CheckListBox.AddGroup('What to backup:', '', 0, nil);
CheckListBox.AddRadioButton(
  'Don''t perform any backup when the program shuts down', '', 0, False, True, nil);
CheckListBox.AddRadioButton(
  'Make a complete backup when the program shuts down', '', 0, False, True, nil);
CheckListBox.AddRadioButton(
  'Only make an essential backup when the program shuts down', '', 0, False, True, nil);

CheckListBox.AddGroup('How to backup:', '', 0, nil);
CheckListBox.AddRadioButton(
  'Perform automatically when the program is shut down', '', 0, False, True, nil);
CheckListBox.AddRadioButton(
  'Prompt the user when the program is shut down', '', 0, False, True, nil);
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up using `TPanel` because of how the control behaves when items are clicked.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: When I click a radio, say on the license agreement page, I get a focus rectangle around the object. When I click in this other control I also get a complete line highlighted in solid colour. Added to that you can still click the two items that have no icons which seems weird. TPanel works OK.

Comment: That's possibly related to your themed installer. I do not have that behaviour.

Comment: Ok, well don’t worry. TPanel works fine. Radio controls are now groups as expected. Thanks.